# PHP - access object const with this in another object

Tags: php, class, oop, scope, constants

I have simple example code where I want to use object operator together with scope resolution to get class constant (PHP 5.5).

```
<?php


class A {
    const MY_CONST = 'This is my const';
}

class B {

    private $property;

    public function __construct(A $a) {    
        $this->property = $a;

        echo $a::MY_CONST."<br />"; // works (1)

        echo A::MY_CONST."<br />"; // works (2)

        $obj = $this->property;

        echo $obj::MY_CONST."<br />"; // works (3)

        echo $this->property::MY_CONST; // doesn't work (4)               
    }

}

$b = new B(new A);
```

The code is tested in PHP 5.5.12, I don't care about compatibility with earlier PHP versions in this question.

**Question is** - is it possible to access object const if the object is set as property of other class as in (4) and you want to use $this together with const name. 1 and 2 obviously works, simple assignment in 3 also works but makes one extra line.

**If it is not possible is there any reason to deny it** or simple PHP developers decided so or simple forgot about making it working? For me it's quite strange that 4 doesn't work but 3 is working without any problem

Comment: You should realize your mistake in the first place: constant is defined as _class_ entity, not _instance_ entity. Even if PHP allows instance de-reference, it's an error in the logic if you want to refer to instance "constant". So if PHP has error here (apparently, it has) - then it's in the thing, that it's allowed class constant de-reference via instance, and not in the thing, that such de-reference is impossible via another class property holder

Comment: Maybe, but in this example I am not thinking about logic only rather about why 3rd case work and 4th doesn't. Either both should work or neither of them in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: Yes, it is possible. But in one of threee round-about ways:

```
$tmp = $this->property;
return $tmp::MY_CONST;
```

Or, IMO, a *bit* more intuitive:

```
$class = get_class($this->property);
return $class::MY_CONST;
```

An alternative way of doing this would be:

```
$r = new RefletionClass($this->property);
return $r->getConstant('MY_CONSTANT');
```

As to the reason why your code generates a parser error, I'm not 100% sure. I can tell you, however, that the PHP grammar is quite complicated, and a tad messy.
I wouldn't be surprized, though, to learn that `$this->foo::BAR` is an expression that trips up the parser, which explains the parse error.

Comment: This solution is even more complex than 3rd case so I'm afraid it's not the best solution (but maybe the only one).

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek: Sorry, didn't notice that you already got it working in the code you posted (should've looked closer)